# Could not translate host name "db" to address: Name does not resolve

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Пытаюсь поработать с докером, есть небольшое приложение с БД.
Сейчас пытаюсь добиться того чтобы вместе запускались и БД и приложения.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN \
 apk add --no-cache postgresql-libs && \
 apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
 python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . .
CMD ["python", "main.py" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.10"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: db_docker_tests

  app:
    restart: always
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
```

setting_db.py

```
database_user: str = 'postgres'
database_password: str = 'pass'
database_host_local: str = 'db'
database_port_local: str = '5432'
database_name: str = 'db_docker_tests'

database_connect_local: str = f"postgresql://{database_user}:{database_password}@{database_host_local}:{database_port_local}/{database_name}"
```

Я запускаю билд (`docker-compose up -d`), все происходит нормально, но когда я смотрю логи, то вижу ошибку: `connection to server at "db" (192.168.32.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`
не понимаю почему хост 192.168.32.2

Подскажите что не так, пересмотрел кучу уроков у всех все работает, нашел на стеке проблему такую же, но решение не помогло, но понимаю что делаю нет.

Обновление
Как я понял в моем случае db = 0.0.0.0
И через dbeaver я могу подключиться к БД. Тогда непонятно в чем проблема у контейнера.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, ваша проблема связана с ошибкой, которая возникла в docker после обновления на более свежую версию, после 4.15. Эта проблема известна и по ней открыто issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6716 первым делом, попробуйте понизить версию docker. Если действительно убеждены что всё в порядке с docker compose. Попробуйте понизить версию docker до 4.15: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4150